# I cannot return the real variable on processed recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have been doing this recursion in javascript; however I cannot return the real value of `x` on return. Instead, it is returning the processed value. The code is doing it's job but it's returning the processed variable on recursion. I tried to store the variable on x, but I still fail.

I want to return the last call stack to get the real variable.

This code returns `0 is Even`, `1 is Even` - how can the code be changed such that these cases would work as expected?

```
function isEven(x) {
    var y =x;
    if (x<0) {
        x = x * -1; 
    }
    if ( x===0 ) {
        return console.log(y+' is Even');
    } else if( x===1 ) {
        return console.log(y+' is Odd');
    } else {  
        return isEven(x-2); 
    }

    // →
    console.log(isEven(10));
    console.log(isEven(-11));
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is. I see the problem that you return `console.log` execution result, which is undefined, and then you try to output it. Your function must return a string, which will be then outputed by `console.log`.

Comment: sorry it was the debugger; I forget. here is a javascript compiler for demo https://repl.it/Cn2w

Comment: I made an edit to your question: You forgot to close your `else` brackets for the `return isEven( x-2 )` - might that have solved your issue?

Comment: the output is still 0 and 1, and also, why is there an undefined when I have return in it?

Comment: @Xenyal - I've rolled back your edit. The OP is asking about their own code, not what you think their code should be. If you think the brackets was the problem post that as an answer, or just as a comment. (Though simply wrapping that `return` in `{}` doesn't change the operation of the function at all...)

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks, I did it out of habit but it shouldn't have been done in this case.

Comment: @Xenyal. Sure, no problem. I have no problem at all with editing the whitespace in somebody's question to fix the indenting and so forth (assuming we're dealing with a language like JS where whitespace/indenting doesn't matter). Just don't like to see actual code changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the initial value using your code.

The simplest way to achieve this goal is to add a function parameter, which will store the original value:

```js
function isEven(x, initial) {
 initial = initial || x; // so that isEven(10) => isEven(10, 10)

if (x<0) {
   x = x * -1; 
}
  if(x===0) {
        return initial+' is Even';
    } else if(x===1) {
        return initial+' is Odd';
    } else 

  return isEven(x-2, initial); 
}

// →
console.log(isEven(10));
console.log(isEven(-11));
```

However, the correct solution is to separate the initial call and recursive calls. For example, it can be achieved using nested functions.
It is also a good idea to abstract logics (boolean) and displayed information (string).

```js
function isEvenString(initial) {
  function isEvenBool(x) {
    if (x < 0) {
      x = x * -1;
    }

    if (x === 0) {
      return true;
    }

    if (x === 1) {
      return false;
    }

    return isEvenBool(x - 2);
  }

  return initial + (isEvenBool(initial) ? " is Even" : " is Odd");
}

// →
console.log(isEvenString(10));
console.log(isEvenString(-11));
```

P.S. Note that this `isEven` function is good for education purposes, but absolutely useless in practice. It takes 1 000 000 function calls to determine that 2 000 000 is even whilst it can be done using one line of code in O(1) operations:

```
function isEvenString(x) { 
  return x % 2 === 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you're trying to do is print the original value that was given, not the final value from the recursion. But you're reassigning `y` every time you recurse, so it doesn't contain the original value.

One solution is to split the function up into a main function and a recursive internal function.

```
function isEven(x) {
    var y =x;
    function isEvenRecurse(x) {
        if (x<0) {
            x = x * -1; 
        }
        if(x===0) {
            return y+' is Even';
        } else if(x===1) {
            return y+' is Odd';
        } else {
            return isEvenRecurse(x-2);
        }
    }
    isEvenRecurse(y);
}
```

Another way is to pass an extra argument to the function when recursing.

```
function isEven(x, y) {
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        y = x;
    }
    if (x<0) {
        x = x * -1; 
    }
    if(x===0) {
        return y+' is Even';
    } else if(x===1) {
        return y+' is Odd';
    } else {
        return isEven(x-2, y);
    }
}
```